# Can I save my vinegar soaked caraway seeds?

Tags: food-safety, spices, pickling

I prepared some quick-pickled onions (the variety that you only keep in the fridge for a few days) and used a "boil the vinegar then pour it over" method. I accidentally dropped about 40g of black caraway seeds into the brine due to my spice container malfunctioning. Due to the pour-over method, I managed to separate most of them. Unfortunately, the seeds are now soaked. Is there a safe way to dry and use them, or will I need to use them quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rinse them in a few changes of water and then dry them throughly in a warm/dry location; they should be fine. If you happen to have a standing pilot oven (old-fashioned these days) that works well for drying things.

You can blot most of the water out with a towel. The main issue is to get them throughly dry, so they don't grow mold.

An alternative would be to jar them in vinegar and put them in the fridge for future use in other pickled foods.

Comment: … or freeze them.